# VBA looping error "subscript out of range"

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an issue with the loop component of the script below and am getting a "subscript out of range error." The goal is to do a find and replace en masse. The first array (DirArray) has the items to find and the second array has the replacements. Here is the code.

```
Sub Replacements()
  Dim X As Long, FindThese As Variant, ReplaceWith As Variant
  Dim DirArray As Variant
  DirArray = Worksheets("f").Range("E1:E562")
  Dim DirArray2 As Variant
  DirArray2 = Worksheets("f").Range("F1:F562")
  FindThese = DirArray
  ReplaceWith = DirArray2
  For X = LBound(FindThese) To UBound(FindThese)
    Worksheets("2").Columns("F:Q").Replace FindThese(X), ReplaceWith(X), xlWhole, , True, , False, False
  Next
  End Sub
```

How can I fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: `DirArray`  and `DirArray2` are 2D arrays.

Comment: Can you explain please? My data is in this format {x,y,z} for first array matching with {c,a,b} for second array - replace x with c for example. and loop through. How would I fix the code? Thanks!

Comment: As BigBen said: even when you read only one column, you will get an 2D array. Use `Worksheets("2").Columns("F:Q").Replace FindThese(X, 1), ReplaceWith(X, 1), xlWhole, , True, , False, False`

Comment: Also consider using `For X = LBound(FindThese, 1) To UBound(FindThese, 1)`, which is explicit in stating the dimension of the array you're considering.

Comment: Since `E1:E562` and `F1:F562` are contiguous ranges, you could just use one array here btw.